# Cell reference in conditional formatting

Tags: excel, reference, formatting, conditional-statements, cell

My apologies if all the text in this document is in German, I'll try to explain it as well as possible.

Basically, this is just a sheet that contains the dates and times an employee was working. All the weekdays are automatically generated, e.g. when the month is set to October 2013, the weekdays automatically update. ("Di" -> "Tu"/tuesday, "Mi" -> "We"/wednesday, ...)
[image: Default look of the excel document. Everything's fine]

This works out alright, so I don't have any problems with that. What the actual goal is, I wanted to make it a little bit better readable by adding thicker lines after every sunday, signalizing the end of the week.

[image: weeks seperated with thick line]

Using the conditional formatting, I've managed to do that for every line. E.g. for line 14, I used the formula **=MOD(VALUE($B$14);7)=1** to determine, if the value in column B and line 14 is in fact a sunday. If the modulus of the weekday divided by 7 is 1, then it is a sunday and the formatting style is applied to those cells.

Now, this formula makes it a little hard to work with. I'd basically have to copy-paste the lines each time and change the line number for each line. I thought it would be possible to make it more dynamic by leaving out the **$-symbol** (*=MOD(VALUE($B1);7)=1*), but for some reason it didn't work for me.

What do I have to type in inside **VALUE** to reference the B-Column in the same line?

Comment: Are the values in column B text or numbers formatted as days?

Comment: @Jerry Yes, they're formatted as weekdays. If I call the VALUE of Sunday, it returns 1, if I call VALUE(Tuesday), it returns 3.

Comment: It's working fine on my excel, though it might be easier with `=WEEKDAY($B1)=1`. Anyway, was cell A1 the active cell when you applied conditional formatting? (A1 selected first, then the range selected so that A1 is slightly less blue than all other selected cells)

Comment: @Jerry `WEEKDAY` also works, thanks for that tip. I'm not exactly sure what you meant with the second question. Eg. I marked the cells A14 to G14 and applied the `=WEEKDAY($B$14)=1` rule, and it worked fine. But if I did `=WEEKDAY($B1)=1` instead, nothing happened. 

Maybe it's slightly different when using the German version of Excel? I hope not :/

Comment: Do you have a formula in column B?

Comment: @barryhoudini Yes, I have a normal formula in column B to "calculate" the weekdays (in this example Oct 01 2013 is Tuesday). But this shouldn't interfere with the conditional formatting, should it?

Comment: Look [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tn1I.png). Do you see that cell A1 is slightly less blue, but more white in the selection? The conditional formatting will apply the rule `=WEEKDAY($B1)=1` to this cell if it's active. If the cell that is whiter was A32, it wouldn't have worked because it's applying `=WEEKDAY($B1)=1` to cell A32. Well, I was using your formula in that picture.

Comment: It's more for my own interest! In English Excel you wouldn't be able to get the day shown as two letters (e.g. "Mo" for Monday) and still keep the cell as a numeric value. I suspect you might be using more complexity than you really need - @Jerry, sorry for cutting across your explanations!

Comment: @Jerry Yes, it works! I wouldn't have guessed that I had to make the whole region selection from A1. You're welcome to leave an official answer, I'll mark it as correct. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @barryhoudini I thought you could always leave two-letter-weekdays by saying "DDD" instead of "DDDD" in the custom formats.

Comment: In english "DDD" will give you "Sun" and "DDDD" will give you "Sunday". No format alone will give you "Su" - "DD" gives a number so for Sunday 6th Oct "DD"= "06"

Comment: OK but I tried in German with "TTT" format and it give me 2 letters - thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the issue was that you were applying your condition on a range on the wrong active cell.

An active cell is the only cell which is slightly less blue in the selected region; for instance, in the picture below, the active cell is A1:

[image: 1]

And if this is the active cell, you will be able to use your formula:

```
=MOD(VALUE($B1);7)=1
```

There's a simpler formula though:

```
=WEEKDAY($B1)=1
```

This means that if the active cell was A32 or H32 in the picture, the formula wouldn't have worked, because the condition for formatting is being applied to the wrong cell!

Comment: +1 Jerry - Note that WEEKDAY is always better - if you switched to 1904 date system then the MOD version wouldn't work......

Comment: @barryhoudini Right. I remember I once started a calendar as from 1900 and I think there was 1 date which caused problems, a 29th February on a supposedly non-leap year I think. I guess I could google that someday to find out why that's the case :)

Comment: Right - MS decided to have 1900 as a leap year when it isn't, apparently for compatability because Lotus had done the same before. That means that 29th Feb 1900 exists when it shouldn't and consequently all the dates before that (1st Jan to 28th Feb 1900) show the incorrect weekday in Excel

Comment: I found a link - John Walkenbach explains it here - http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/oddity/the_intentional_date_bug/